# How to disable sign in pop-up on SFSafariViewController call on B2C sign in

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup, sfsafariviewcontroller

On launch, my app automatically makes an authorization call to my B2C tenant using openid-appauth and a popup saying

```
                  "MyApp" Wants to use 
                "b2clogin.com" to Sign-in
             This allows the app and website to 
                share information about you.
            -----------------------------------
                     Cancel | Continue
```

appears before showing my sign in page in SFSafariViewController .

I want to remove/disable this popup and automatically continue to the sign in page.

I am new to iOS development and also new to objective-c programming. I don't have any idea on how to solve this problem on my own. I tried searching stackoverflow for similar problems but unfortunately I couldn't find anything that could help me.

I am using the code from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-ios-native-appauth.

I expect that the pop-up will be removed/disabled when the sign in page is initiated using SFSafariViewController.

Comment: Is the popup shown in the Safari view controller?  I suspect that you can't remove it, because it is a privacy warning generated by the sign in page, to warn the user that by using their credentials they will be sharing information with your app.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks :D